# Convex conjugate of average Fisher information measure

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory, fisher-information

What is a possible [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) of the function $\rho \mapsto \int (\nabla \log \rho(x))^2 \rho(x) dx$?

(Suppose $\rho$ is a sufficiently integrable probability density function on a $d$-dimensional domain.)